# How to calculate probability for card game

Tags: probability, probability-distributions, conditional-probability, card-games

I am creating a card game for a project and I need to calculate the probability and distribution when playing the game. I do not know how to go about it, and would appreciate some insight on starting.

The point of the game is to choose a card to call, and if it is revealed you win. The game works as there are 2 sections, one of 5 cards which if your card is called you get 150% of your money bet, and the other section which is 3 cards but you recieve 200% of your money bet.

If anyone could help on how to start calculating the distributions, it would be greatly appreciated. Thanks.

Comment: Could you please clarify the question a bit more perhaps with an example. For instance, what does the calling have to do with two sections?

Comment: There is a great deal of clarification needed.  First, are you using a standard 52 card deck which has been well shuffled?  After the deck is shuffled, you draw five cards face down and put it in a pile and three more cards face down and put it in a separate pile.  From here, a player may choose any one card (e.g. ace of spades) and any one pile and bet any amount of money they wish.  If the named card happens to be in the selected pile, they "win"... but how much?...(continued)

Comment: ...  If I bet 1 dollar on the five card pile to contain the ace of spades and win, do I get my 1 dollar back and an additional 1.5 dollars for a *total* returned of 2.5 dollars i.e. a net increase of 1.5 dollars?  Or do I get my 1 dollar back and an additional 50 cents for a *total* returned of 1.5 dollars i.e. a net increase of 50 cents?  Can you confirm also that the person is only allowed to make one bet at a time and may not select multiple card names to watch for and may not select multiple piles to look through?  Or in betting do you get to look through both piles?

Comment: Sorry for not clarifying enough. An example of running through it is that I place a 1dollar  bet on the number 7 and I choose the 5 card pile. If a 7 is revealed in that pile I recieve $1.5 back. Another example is that if I place a $1 bet on the number 7 and choose the 3 card pile, if it is revealed I receive $2 back. Only the face of the card matters not the suit.